# How to add response code to response XML in Java web service using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, soap

I have made a web service using Eclipse IDE. This is the request XML that is being generated when I use Soapui to test it.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fil="http://files/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <fil:ServiceCall2>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <arg0>71896</arg0>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <arg1>test10</arg1>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <arg2>pdf</arg2>
          </fil:ServiceCall2>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the response xml on accessing the service with parameters

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:ServiceCall2Response xmlns:ns2="http://files/"/>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I want a Java code so that I can add response code tags in my response XML.

Comment: How are you constructing the soap Response ? Can you post that code snippet ?

Comment: I am using that server , impl , publisher file RPC soap web service and then testing the service in soap ui here is code..

Comment: its too long .. the bottom line is I am hitting an existing web service and creating  a service out of it.. now all i need is to add the response code to the above response xml....

Comment: Where does eclipse and code come into picture here ? You are using SOAP WS to call a server exposed Web Service ?

Comment: this is my webmothod..

Comment: public void ServiceCall2(String dockIndex , String fileName , String fileExtension){ 
 try {SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory2 = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
   SOAPConnection soapConnection2 = soapConnectionFactory2.createConnection();
   String url2 = "http://10.5.4.122:7003/omnidocs_ws/services/NGOImageEnableServiceImp?wsdl";
   SOAPMessage soapResponseObj2 = soapConnection2.call(createSOAPRequest(dockIndex), url2);
   ByteArrayOutputStream out2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   soapResponseObj2.writeTo(out2);
   printSOAPResponse(soapResponseObj2);

Comment: i called the web service using eclipse and java code..

Comment: and made a web service using the same..

Comment: ^ Please edit your question and add that in. Comments are not a suitable place to show (readable) code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something like this.

```
    SOAPMessage soapResponseObj2 = soapConnection2.call(createSOAPRequest(dockIndex), url2);
    QName name = new QName("responseCode");
    SOAPElement symbol = soapResponseObj2.getSOAPBody().addChildElement(name);
    symbol.addTextNode("0");
```

Refer : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/819-3669/bnbhw/index.html

Comment: thanx it worked but there is still one problem i am getting it on the reponse of the service i am hitting ... how do i get in in the response of the service i created??

Comment: wherever you are creating your service response add a tag to the response body

Comment: i am not creating it manually i am using these two files as server and publisher

Comment: package files;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class DownloadDocInFilePublisher {
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:9873/DownloadDocInFile", new DownloadDocInFileImpl());  
        System.out.println("Service started test it...");
         }  
 }

Comment: package files;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface DownloadDocInFileServer {
 WebMethod public void ServiceCall2(String dockIndex , String fileName , String fileExtension);
}